# When sorting by multiple fields in Firestore with startAt and endAt not working correctly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am doing a document filter functionality.

The problem is that when I receive a filter for the "max_players" and "name" fields, it returns an empty array when there are documents that meet the conditions.

The error occurs when doing startAt and endAt when there is more than one OrderBy and I don't understand the reason.

**Technologies:**

- Angular
- Firebase - Firestore

**Service:**

```
if (filter.players != null) {
      const option: string = filter.players.substring(0, 1);

      if (option == '+') {
        ref = ref.where('max_players', '>=', 8)
      } else {
        const num_players: number = parseInt(option);
        ref = ref.where('max_players', '>=', num_players)
      }
    }

if (filter.text != null) {
  if (filter.players != null) {
    ref = ref.orderBy('max_players').orderBy('name').startAt(filter.text).endAt(filter.text + '\uf8ff');
  }else{
    ref = ref.orderBy('name').startAt(filter.text).endAt(filter.text + '\uf8ff');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firebase limitation

Documentation:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2577#

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).